# Batch file, removing double quote but giving blank .txt

Tags: batch-file, cmd, sendmail, blat

My goal is to remove the double quote and send resource of .txt file as body mail through blat, I've seen a lot of question regarding this(removing double quotes).. but I can't figure out, where am I doing wrong. Here is my code

```
set "now=%date:~4%" 
for /f %%i in ('FORFILES /D %now% /m *.csv /c "cmd /c echo @fname"')
do @set MyVariable=%%~i > C:\temp\count.txt
CD C:\temp\blat3217\full
blat C:\temp\count.txt -p user -s "Incoming_File_Alert" -to mymail@mail.com
```

EDIT:

This giving output blank.

EDIT 2 :

if I switch out line number 2 with this `FORFILES /D %now% /m *.csv /c "cmd /c echo @fname" > C:\temp\count.txt`

The output is like this

> ```
> "407232_341600"
> "TW39369763_341610"
> "1726_341592"
> "407316_341601"
> "16001_341597"
> "100001317_341590"
> "407367_341602"
> "DHB11838_341593"
> "407439_341606"
> "407556_341604"
> "2373_341595"
> "ALL1020-461_341614"
> "407382_341605"
> "3598_341613"
> "PO051334_341589"
> "407537_341607"
> "407222_341598"
> "TW39369964_341611"
> "407403_341608"
> ```

Comment: Which double quotes? I see three sets.

Comment: @anub13, please delete your comments and edit your question with any additional information you have.

Comment: The `DO` has to be on the same line as the `FOR`.  I think what you are trying to do is this. `for /f "delims=" %%i in ('FORFILES /D %now% /m *.csv') do >>C:\temp\count.txt echo %%~ni`

Comment: Hi Squashman, thanks I will try later, at the moment occupied. Be right back soon.

Comment: just did @Squashman
Thanks, now will try your suggestion.

Comment: Just try and works! but.. is there a way to get rid of %%~ni showing in body mail? EDIT: I dont know why previously %%~ni was showing, edit here and there and its gone

EDIT 2: when running second time, its not overwritting previous .txt file. I think I need to delete if exist..

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try for this batch file :

```bat
@echo off
set "SourcePath=C:\Users\user1\Documents\Work\warehouse\"
set "now="
set "Ext=csv"
Call :GetCurrentDate
set "outputfile=C:\temp\count.txt"
If exist "%outputfile%" Del "%outputfile%"
CD /D "%SourcePath%"
@for /f "delims=" %%i in ('FORFILES /D %now% /m *.%Ext%') do (
    echo %%~ni >> "%outputfile%"
)
If exist "%outputfile%" start "" "%outputfile%" & exit
::********************************************************************************
:GetCurrentDate
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
set MM=%dt:~4,2%
set DD=%dt:~6,2%
set now=%DD%/%MM%/%YYYY%
exit /b
::********************************************************************************
```

Comment: Shouldn't need to set the FOR variable to an environmental variable before redirecting the output.  Also shouldn't need `/c "cmd /c echo @fname"` because you can get the base file name without the extension with the `FOR` variable modifier.  So the base code could really just look like this: `for /f "delims=" %%i in ('FORFILES /D %now% /m *.csv') do >>C:\temp\count.txt echo %%~ni`

Comment: Hi Hackoo,

Thanks for responding, just now running your suggestion, it doesn't give output at all. Instead, its opening new .txt file and wrote 

!MyVariable!

Comment: @Hackoo
OK, will do.

Comment: @Hackoo just now tried, and the output is exactly the same as before, I assume, its confuse where is the source file is?
Because I don't see the source syntax/variable.

Comment: @anub13 what is the path of the folder that contains `*.csv`  ?

Comment: C:\Users\user1\Documents\Work\warehouse

Comment: @anub13 re-check my last edit based on your given path

Comment: @Hackoo

it works!
Thanks, very appreciate it.. but I prefer my own code because its easier to understand. Once again, thanks very appreciated your effort.

Comment: @Hackoo thanks, just check again your answer it has syntax to delete previous existing file.. I will update it to my code. (y)
was trying second time with dummy file, its duplicating instead overwriting previous .txt file

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Squashman,
my problem solved with his suggestion.. looked like this, if anyone interested

```
CD C:\Users\user1\Documents\Work\warehouse
set "now=%date:~4%"
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('FORFILES /D %now% /m *.csv')do >> C:\temp\count.txt echo %%~ni 
CD C:\temp\blat3217\full
blat C:\temp\count.txt -p user -s "Warehouse_Incoming_File_Alert" -to mymail@mymail.com
```

EDIT 1:

Mistype.

EDIT 2:

Above is duplicating if we don't delete previous existing .txt file

here is adding syntax delete previous file, thanks to Hackoo answer

```
CD C:\Users\user1\Documents\Work\warehouse
set "now=%date:~4%"
set "outputfile= C:\temp\count.txt"

If exist %outputfile% del %outputfile%

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('FORFILES /D %now% /m *.csv') do >> %outputfile% echo %%~ni

CD C:\temp\blat3217\full
blat C:\temp\count.txt -p user -s "Warehouse_Incoming_File_Alert" -to  mymail@mymail.com
```